# How can I print different things for every if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I'm trying to make a hangman game and  I'm trying to print a different body part each time when the user gets it wrong but instead its just printing it all at once. how do I get the code to print it at different guesses

```
import random

list = ['dog', 'cat', 'snake', 'hamster' 'fish']

list = random.choice(list)

guesses = ''

turns = 100

while turns > 0:

    failed = 0

    for char in list:
        if char in guesses:

            print(end=" ")

            print("correct")

        else:

            print("_")

            print(end=" ")

            failed += 1

    if failed == 0:

        print("you win")

        print("The word is: ",list)

        break

    print()

    guess = input("Guess a charcter:")

    guesses += guess

    if guess not in list:

        print(" _______")

        print("|       |")

        print("|       |")

        print("|       |")

        print(" _______")

        if guess not in list :

            print(" _______")

            print("|       |")

            print("|       |")

            print("|       |")

            print(" _______")

            print("   ||")

            print("\  ||  /")

            print(" \ || /")

            print("  \||/")

            print("   ||")

            print("   ||")

            print("   ||")
```

Comment: What you you expect `if guess not in list : if guess not in list :` to do?

Comment: print a different body part each time they get the answer wrong. so for example the first time they get it wrong it only prints the head. The second time the body and the third time the legs.

Comment: That's not how programming logic works.

Comment: so i cant get it to print a different thing each time the user put in the wrong input?

Comment: Sure, but not by simply nesting identical conditions. I suggest that you take a step back and create a flowchart of your intended program logic. That'll help you see that you need decisions and not simple conditions to handle that.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `list` as a variable name, because it shadows the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) type.